# Luks encrypted USB startup key

Tags: linux, debian, luks

I'm looking to use an encrypted USB drive as a key to unlock my system's root partition. Putting `sda3_crypt UUID=5fa565ce-aa25-46f2-b730-e5b26f66db80 /dev/disk/by-label/drive:/key luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev` in `/etc/crypttab` works but it's using an unencrypted partition on the drive. I've tried

```
key UUID=9ed4add0-81e8-41ab-b1fe-0412e879eef0 none luks
sda3_crypt UUID=5fa565ce-aa25-46f2-b730-e5b26f66db80 /dev/mapper/key:/key luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev
```

but it never prompts me for the password to the USB drive's partition. It just doesn't boot. What am I missing? I'm running Debian 8 Jessie. One thing I've noticed is it seems to always want to decrypt my root partition first. If I have my crypttab setup like it is above where my flash drive is the first entry and my root partition is the second entry and I use password authentication on both so I don't need to worry about whether or not the key file is accessible it asks me for the password to my root partition first and then my flash drive. It should be the reverse given the order in crypttab.

Comment: Which distro? And don't they have a howto in their wiki?

Comment: @frostschutz I edited my post to include that but I haven't found a whole lot of info on doing this in the first place. I've found lots of stuff for using unencrypted flash drives but not ones that are encrypted.

Comment: What is the reason for preferring an encrypted USB drive as a key? What benefit does that give over an unencrypted one, and what is the use case / attack you're trying to prevent by encrypting the USB drive?

Comment: @einonm I don't trust having a psychical object containing the key to my system unless that object is also encrypted.

Comment: Ok, one popular method of ensuring the key is hidden is to fill the USB with random data (no filesystem), and choose a random 4k block as the LUKS key. Does that not satisfy your need?

Comment: @einonm that's interesting? How would you do that?

Comment: IIRC, Fill a USB drive with random data, and mount it on the system as a block device, with an offset. Use the first n bytes of the mounted device as your LUKS key. The offset can be any bytes within a block.