# Booting encrypted root with encrypted USB key

Tags: boot, usb-drive, luks, initramfs, cryptsetup

Running Debian 11 with grub, full disk encryption (no LVM) on /dev/sdb2, unencrypted /boot/efi on /dev/sdb1.

At boot, I want two options:

1. typing password
2. plugging an encrypted USB key (which stores a LUKS key-file in order to unlock /dev/sdb2).

(same use case as [Luks encrypted USB startup key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303873/luks-encrypted-usb-startup-key) - except I want no password typing at all when I insert USB key).

My USB key is encrypted, so I need to automatically unlock it at boot. For this purpose, I have created a LUKS key-file which is stored in /boot/efi.

Here is my resulting /etc/crypttab:

```
USB-KEY /dev/disk/by-label/USB-KEY_LUKSCONTAINER  /boot/efi/USB-KEY.key  luks,keyscript=/bin/cat
cryptroot UUID=xxxx-xxxx--xxxx-xxx  /dev/disk/by-label/USB-KEY:/secret.key:20 luks,discard,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev
```

I've updated /etc/fstab for USB-KEY to be automatically mounted :

```
/dev/mapper/USB-KEY
UUID=yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy  /mnt/USB-KEY  ext4  nosuid,rw  0 0
```

At boot, although USB key is inserted, I am stuck on cryptsetup prompt - and if I type my LUKS password I obtain this message: "cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?". Where am I wrong?

Comment: `which is stored in /etc/keys/` is that file in the USB drive or ... where?

Comment: /etc/keys/ is on /dev/sb2 (root filesystem)

Comment: So, the key to unlocking the USB is on sdb2 and the key to unlocking sdb2 is on the USB?

Comment: Aha! you're rightI The key should be on unencrypted /bot/efi (/dev/sdb1).

Comment: I have edited my post with correct folder for secret.key. Still same error message.